# MySQL three table join with sum

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have three tables

**Student**

```
studenid  stuname  
101       john     
102       aron     
103       mary     
104       lucy
```

**Subject**

```
studenid  subjid  subjname   
101       1       maths      
102       2       science    
103       3       computer   
104       4       english
```

**Marks**

```
subjid  mark   
1       50
2       40
3       55
4       60
1       40
2       55
3       60
```

I want output like this where studenid (sum of mark as total)

```
studenid  stuname  mark     
101       john     90      
102       aron     95    
103       mary     115   
104       lucy     60
```

Thank you in advance for yout help, i want output like this even join query or subquery which is best for timing

Comment: Are marks per student? If yes, where's the studentid column?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please share your attempt and explain where it's not working.

Comment: How marks and students are related

Comment: A small design point: the database is de-normalised - the subject name should be in a separate table, so each name is listed once. The way it's done now, you'll list the subject name repeatedly - once for every student who studies that subject. That's duplication and is not in line with relational database design principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just requires a straight left join across all tables, with an aggregation by student.

```
SELECT
    st.studenid,
    st.stuname,
    COALESCE(SUM(m.mark), 0) AS mark
FROM Student st
LEFT JOIN Subject su
    ON st.studenid = su.studenid
LEFT JOIN Marks m
    ON su.subjid = m.subjid
GROUP BY
    st.studenid,
    st.stuname;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that if `studenid` be a primary key in the `Student` table, then strictly we would only need to aggregate by this column alone.

Comment: Let me check, Thanks you

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen, It's Worked for me, Great :)